# Left click not working on touchpad or mouse

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, mouse, touchpad, mouse-click

I have a very strange problem.

I own a Lenovo ThinkPad E530c. At one point in its life, the left click on the touchpad simply decided to stop working. That keyboard-bound left-click button also did not work. Right click worked fine.

As I don't use my laptop very often (and when I do, I use a mouse, where both clicks were working fine), I practically forgot about the problem thinking it was probably a driver issue and I was too lazy at the time to figure it out.

Fast forward to today. I boot up my laptop and remember that it didn't work. I tried reinstalling the drivers (nearly fresh copy of W7, by the way), that did not help. I figured windows must have messed something up, so I booted an Ubuntu Live CD. Sure enough, both clicks worked fine.

I then installed Ubuntu, and lo and behold, after installation, neither touchpad-click, nor the keyboard-button click for left clicking did not work (on Ubuntu). And get this... The left click did not work on my USB mouse either.

Summa summarum, there is no way for me to left click on Ubuntu, and I can only left click with my mouse on Windows 7.

What the hell could be going on? I plan on installing Arch tomorrow to see if that will help it, but this is a very odd problem I believe.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Maybe a modifier key (Ctrl, Alt, Shift) is being held down unintentionally (or stuck), and that's causing programs to interpret it as, say, "Ctrl+click" instead of "Click", and most programs don't know what to do with a Ctrl+click? Just a thought. Try jiggling your modifier keys.

Comment: @allquixotic - while I am not saying that is definitely not the problem, I have so far opened and closed the laptop case half a dozen times. Plus, I don't think that would really explain the completely erratic behavior I have - none working on Ubuntu, one working on Windows, both right clicks working. But I will check that too.

Comment: Try lifting the button at the ends using a pin or anything slightly and blow the compressed air inside it and also at its sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the "problem". @allquixotic was partially right in his comment - it seems that TrackPoint is having some issues causing the clicks/taps to not be working. After disabling the TrackPoint, all "clicks" work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I've had my computer now for several years and all of a sudden the left mouse button and the ability to tap on the touch pad stopped.

My laptop is out of warranty and before buying a new one, i wanted to see if I could fix this.

I read hundreds of forums and they all said you are screwed. That you have to send it back. None actually posted a solution.

I took the entire computer apart and finally found the problem and here's the problem and the solution:

There are two ribbons that connect to your left mouse button and the tapping ability of the touchpad. The ribbons aren't that long, and with continued handling of the laptop and picking it up by the corner, you cause the laptop to flex, which in turn pulls on the two ribbons. Eventually the two ribbons will pop out of place.

As a result, the mouse pad can still move around, and the right moust button will still work, but nothing else.

Here's the solution:

1. Take off the cover to the hard drive and memory.
2. Depending on your computer, under one of the covers you will find the screw that holds the keyboard in. It is usually labeled with a picture of the keyboard.
3. Unscrew that screw and then open your laptop.
4. Take a small flat edge, guitar pick, or a credit card and pry the top of your keyboard up to release it from your laptop. The bottom of the keyboard will come unhooked.
5. There is a ribbon under your keyboard, go ahead and lift the black tab to pull the ribbon out and put the keyboard to the side. This will give you plenty of room for the repair needed.
6. Towards the bottom you will see two ribbons. These ribbons are the ones that have become disconnected.
7. Pull the black tab up on both of the ribbon slots, and then insert the ribbons all the way and then push the black tabs back down.
8. Reinstall the keyboard ribbon in the same way.
9. Push the keyboard back into position and then flip the computer over and put the screw back in that holds the keyboard.
10. Screw the covers back on the memory and hard drive and you are done.

Everything works now perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Un-installation and Re-installation of the UltraNav driver will help to solve your problem

Go to Control Panel -> Device Manager -> Mice and other Pointing Devices -> 
Double-click on UltraNav device (A new window will appear) -> 
Click on Driver -> Click Uninstall to remove the driver ->
Restart your system -> Windows will then install a generic driver that should allow you to use the Touchpad ->
Now install Lenovo version of Touchpad driver ->
For Windows 7 or Vista users, [click here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds035047) or
Windows 8 users please [click here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds035046) to re-install the UltraNav driver.

Comment: The OP says they still have the problem in Ubuntu, how is uninstalling the driver on Windows going to help??